# Eclipse: how to mark occurrences in file opened from History

Tags: version-control, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT (Kepler & Luna) and I've found the *Mark Occurrences* feature to be really helpful, especially the variables occurrences/write occurrences.

But when I open a c or c++ file from the *History View* (right click on a file, Team, Show in history, then double click on a version), no occurrences are marked anymore.

Is there a way to enable the *Mark Occurrences* there? Because I'm back to Ctrl+F or Ctrl+K, which are not as helpful...

Note that with java files it works.

Comment: Mark Occurrences, along with most of semantic highlighting features are not implemented in the CEditor when files are opened from the history. e.g. in addition to Mark Occurrences, disabled pre-processor blocks, SDK calls (like printf) and other such features are not supported. I am not sure what the blocking issue is without more investigation, and I note there is no current bug/feature request open on this, so could you file one? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT&component=cdt-editor

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I filed a feature request for the CEditor, with the help of your comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=483386

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to submit the bug request. If you stick that in an answer it would seem appropriate to me for you to accept that answer. When the bug gets fixed, you can edit the answer. The Eclipse community benefits greatly from having these bug reports submitted. Of course, you know what I am going to say next: patches always welcome!

Comment: PS identifying the related bug (176036) was very useful, the extra effort in doing bugzilla searches was well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out (cf. question comments) that when files are opened from history, the *Mark Occurences* and most of semantic highlighting features are not (yet) supported in the CEditor. An enhancement request has been filed in Eclipse's Bugzilla: [Bug 483386 - Semantic highlighting features not implemented in the CEditor for files opened from the history](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=483386).